# How to use on_press event for a button that has been added dynamically kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following code where a `Button` is added to a `Grid Layout` everytime the `test_press` method is called. What I'd like to be able to do is change to a different screen when one of these buttons is pressed, but I'd like each `Button` that's been created to go to a different screen - which screen it goes to isn't important at the moment. How would I go about implementing something like this?

```
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)

class Finder(Screen):
    layout_profiles = ObjectProperty(None)

    def test_press(self):
        Btn1 = Button(size_hint_y=None, height=75)
        self.layout_profiles.add_widget(Btn1)

class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [Finder(name="finder")]
        for screen in screens:
            sm.add_widget(screen)

        sm.current = "information"
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<Finder>:
    name: "finder"
    layout_profiles: layout_profiles

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                text: "Test"
                on_release: app.root.current = "login"

        FloatLayout:
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                md_bg_color: 0.2, 0.6, 1, 1
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: root.ids.nav_layout.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

            Label:
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                text: "Holding text"
                font_size: 20
                multiline: True
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.125, "y": 0.7}
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint: 0.75, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: "center"

            ScrollView:
                size_hint: 0.95, 0.6
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.025, "top": 0.65, "bottom": 0.2}
                do_scroll_x: False
                GridLayout:
                    cols: 1
                    id: layout_profiles
                    size_hint_y: None
                    spacing: 10
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos

            BoxLayout:
                cols: 1
                Button:
                    text: "Add widget"
                    size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "top": 0.1}
                    on_release: root.test_press()
```

Also apologies if the title (or description!) isn't that clear, I wasn't sure how to describe it.

The "Add widget" `Button` is just there to mimic the eventual goal where the buttons will be added dependent on some information feeding in from a database.

Comment: This is more of a "How would I go about it question" than anything that's specific I want to change about some code

Comment: Your question is specific that requires a specific code. Is it so complicated to provide an MRE?

Comment: Ok thanks, I've just edited the code

Comment: When you make the button, bind a function to its `on_press` event that does what you want.